# HDFS as Liferay file storage

Tags: hdfs, liferay, liferay-7

I use Liferay 7.1.1 GA2. Currently this version of Liferay does not support a HDFS as a document repository, as described in https://dev.liferay.com/discover/deployment/-/knowledge_base/7-1/document-repository-configuration 
Is there a possibility of using HDFS as a Liferay document repository? In older version of liferay it is possible using hook plugin mechanism, which mechanism can use to implement this functionality in Liferay 7.1?

Comment: It's possible if someone implements the connector and share with us

Comment: There is an examples of those connectors with another types of filesystems?

Comment: How to develop this connector?

Comment: The answer to the yes/no question in the Q text above is: Yes. The implicit "How to" question from your comment however is out of scope for stackoverflow. I'd recommend to look at one of the existing store implementation (after all, Liferay is open source, and the configured store implementations are named by their java class name). The interface that you'll need to implement is quite narrow.

Comment: It is possible using cloning liferay repository or there is an another mechanism(f.e., hook) for implement that?